# Open MPI with icc: "Open MPI requires a C99 compiler"

Tags: openmpi, icc

If I run

```
../configure CC=icc CXX=icpc F77=ifort FC=ifort
```

the configuring stops with

```
============================================================================
== Compiler and preprocessor tests
============================================================================

*** C compiler and preprocessor
checking for gcc... (cached) icc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether icc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for icc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether icc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking for icc option to accept ISO C99... unsupported
configure: WARNING: Open MPI requires a C99 compiler
configure: error: Aborting.
```

I'm trying to build Open MPI 3.0.0 from source. I'm using the Intel compilers version 18.0.0 20170811. The environment is Arch Linux.

Why is Open MPI having a problem with icc not being C99 compliant?

Comment: Have a look at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-building-open-mpi-with-the-intel-compilers  and https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#build-intel-compilers

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Specifying CFLAGS="-std=c99" didn't make a difference.

Comment: @VladimirF I checked those websites but I still believe I'm doing everything correctly.

Comment: I'm surprised that nothing comes up when I google this issue. What I'm trying to do is clearly a standard procedure. Maybe there's something different in the newest versions of OpenMPI or the Intel compilers.

Comment: It might be the new OpenMPI 3 problem. Can you have a look into the `config.log` file to see which exact test was performed and what kind of error was reported?

Comment: I looked at the error message and tried to compile the failing test manually. The compilation aborts with the error message `In file included from ../test.c(99):
/usr/include/stdlib.h(133): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
  extern _Float128 strtof128 (const char *__restrict __nptr,
         ^` The same source file compiles in a different system where I have the same Intel compilers but the GCC version is different.

Comment: As usual, the error message generated by the Autotools is misleading because this has nothing to do with the C99 standard.

Comment: It seems the same issue is addressed here https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/742701. There might actually be a problem with the latest Intel compiler.

Comment: It could also be because intel compilers were installed on an unsupported OS. Version 18.0.0 is supports Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I hit the above problem with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the latest ICC if used in combination with glibc 2.26. The problem is still present with version 18.0.0. For now, the fix is to include the flag `-D_Float128=__float128`:

```
../configure CC=icc CXX=icpc FC=ifort CFLAGS="-D_Float128=__float128"
```

Comment: @pds Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use the classic C++ you can choose to compile with C99

```
../configure C99=icc CXX=icpc FC=ifort
```